# didEnterRegion of LocationManager not called ever

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cllocationmanager

I am tired of finding the problem with this but was unable to get why this happens that the Location Manager's delegate method `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` is not called ever. I test this in my iPhone but it doesn't work. Please tell me what I am missing. My source code is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    manager.delegate = self;
    dist = 100;
    coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.004686, 74.554088);
    region=[[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:dist identifier:@"emanuele"];
    [manager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:10];
    return YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"Enter Region.");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Got it..." message:@"You have Entered the Location." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
//    [alert release];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Got it..." message:@"You have Exited the Location." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
//    [alert release];
}
```

Can anybody figure out what's wrong with??
I have searched many demos and source codes but most of them end with `didUpdateToLocation`, which is called in my case, but I have problem with `didEnter` and `didExit`. I have also implemented the `didFailWithError` but it does not do the thing. Please give any clue why these two methods are not called. or give me any link that calls these methods, I found no examples/source for these methods. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to implement `locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:` to see if you get some kind of error?

Comment: @HeikoG: No, I am not using ARC.

Comment: @Pfitz: Yes, I have implemented that method, but it does not give any error (the control never goes inside the method.)...

Comment: how are you declaring your region property? init as new and then add. CLRegion *newRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter.......

Comment: @Nik Burns:  coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.004686, 78.554088);
region=[[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coord radius:dist identifier:@"emanuele"];

Comment: probably that helps on you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html, briefly, the `regionMonitoringAvailable` is deprecated in iOS7+.

Answer (score 1):

is your header file declared as a CLLocationManagerDelegate?

once you setup the region for monitoring you should test by removing that element of the code and then check for the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key when launching like this:

```
 if ([launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"]){

        NSLog(@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey - fired");
        if(locman == nil){
            locman = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];


        locman.delegate = self;
        locman.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        }

    }
```

The location manager delegate will then be called and didEnter and didExit should fire ok.

Comment: good practise to also use kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters or equivalent for the accuracy.

Comment: thank you very very much for the answer. Now the problem is that the control never goes inside the if...any idea why this happens? I have set background modes as voip,location and audio, in the info.plist file. I have also set the delegate and implemented CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol to the appDelegate. The problem seems too silly but It has become serious.

Comment: you dont need the voip location or audio entries in the info.plist for didEnterRegion callbacks. They work as long as the app is monitoring the correct region. Have you tested on the simulator with the correct lat/long? if you have successfully registered the region for monitoring then with the app completely closed you will get the callback when you change the simulator location.

Comment: just for clarification: you are trying to get notified while the app is running and not while it is in the background

Comment: @Pfitz: yes, I know, I put the alertview for testing only. I know it won't be displayed while the app is in the background. but in any case it is not been displayed.

Comment: @prashantsolanki your delegate will **not** be called if your app is in the background

Comment: @Pfitz: but it prints log when the app is in background. However, in the app, I have to pop-up some notification (along with small sound) to tell user that this place has come. Won't it be fine if I use this delegate (as it prints this delegate, there should be some mechanism to pop-up some alertview-like when the app is in background).

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad`, add the following code

```
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get didEnterRegion and didExitRegion only after I enabled Background App Refresh in general settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `didDetermineState` as well? `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` are only called on enter/exit, but from what I understand if you're in the region and not actually moving, `didDetermineState` will tell if you if you are currently in the region.